# CodeIgniter 404 Page Not Found htaccess wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp

I'm working on a CodeIgniter application that was previously developed.

The issue that I'm getting is a page not found and I have installed on wamp.

Here is the .htaccess file that I'm currently using for the app (not the wamp one).

```
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
    RewriteRule ^(index\.php|css|js|fonts|images|uploads|audio) - [PT,L]

    # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
    # RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

How do I go about fixing the 404 issue? Would I change the wamp .htaccess file?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: If this is a "previously developed" application, Is this "Page not found" expected to be found? Or are you just asking how to deal with pages that don't actually exist?

Comment: The page does exist and I'm not expecting to find Page not Found.  They exist in the views directory.

Comment: And an example of the URL to this non existing, existing page would be? Do any pages work?

Comment: Ok, here you go...  The main page: http://localhost/sitename/ works and then I would go to a different page: http://localhost/sitename/partners. That is where I'm having the issues. It currently stored on the following folder: \www\foldername\ using wamp.

Comment: So in this case partners is a controller name? 1st test then - does localhost/sitename/index.php/partners work?

Comment: No, in fact, I'm getting a page not found. Using the following url: http://localhost/sitename/index.php/partners.

Comment: Ok Next...Just for fun, if you create yourself a test controller call it Test.php with the class name of Test with a constructor and in the index function put in echo "hello"... what happens then?

Comment: Nothing.. Could it be way the app is set up and since I'm using it on wamp it could cause problems?

Comment: Well the answer is yes :) But just trying to go through the number of things that could be the cause...

Comment: What do you have in your $config['base_url']; ? That is under application/config/config.php. Also in your WAMP you might need to enable mod_rewrite - you can look up how to do that.

Comment: right now it is $config['base_url'] = ''

Answer (score 1):

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /FOLDERNAME/    #Add your foldername in place of FOLDERNAME

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|css|js|fonts|images|uploads|audio) - [PT,L]

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
# RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you have any other htacess file in root?

Comment: No.. However, I'm using wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below .htacccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Hope this can help you.